# A PHP/pthreads Thread class can't use array?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I've found a PECL pthread `Thread` can't use an array object. What can I do to find the cause?

Code example:

```
   class my extends Thread {

           public function __construct() {
                   $this->arr = array();
                   $this->id  = 0;
           }
           public function run() {
                   while (true) {
                           $this->wait();
                   }
           }

           public function add() {
                   $this->id = rand(0, 1000);
                   $this->arr[] = rand(0, 1000);
                   var_dump($this->id);//this is rand
                   var_dump($this->arr);//this is empty array()
                   $this->notify();
           }
   }

   $my = new my();
   $my->start();
   while (true) {
           sleep(1);
           $my->add();
   }
```

Comment: There is no method `add()` :?

Comment: @user2058508: I am trying to unable pthreads in my php. But not able to do it. Can you please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 37):

## The Problem

PHP is a shared nothing environment: This means that each process (or thread) must have it's own copy of the interpreter, all modules, and user code.

The `HashTable` structure which not only supports PHP arrays, but is used throughout the PHP code base, was never intended to be manipulated by multiple contexts.

The memory manager, which would be invoked whenever you set a new member of an array (equivalent of malloc), unset one (equivalent of free), or update one (equivalent of free then malloc), is an integral part of the shared nothing architecture, and among other things is specifically designed to disallow any context to free memory that was allocated by another context, since this constitutes a violation of shared nothing.

The Virtual Machine assumes that it is the only context manipulating an array.

All extension code makes the same assumption.

The consequences for ignoring the rules - share nothing - are dire: You crash PHP.

All of this makes allowing you to store and manipulate an actual array in multiple contexts unrealisable, and should make it undesirable whatever.

## PHP5

Arrays will be serialized upon setting them as a member of a `Threaded` object.

You should replace your usage of arrays with `Threaded` objects.

A `Threaded` object can be manipulated *as if* it were an array.

Here is something to get you started:

```
<?php
class Test extends Thread {
    public function __construct(Threaded $storage) {
        $this->storage = $storage; 
    }

    public function run(){
        $i = 0;
        while(++$i < 10) {
            $this->storage[]=rand(0,1000);
        }

        $this->synchronized(function($thread){
            $thread->stored = true;
            $thread->notify();
        }, $this);
    } 
}

$storage = new Threaded();
$my = new Test($storage);
$my->start();

$my->synchronized(function(Thread $thread){
    while (!$thread->stored) {
        $thread->wait();
    }
}, $my);

var_dump($storage);
?>
```

## PHP7

pthreads v3 (PHP7) introduces the concepts of automatic immutability for `Threaded` objects.

Quote from my [blog](http://blog.krakjoe.ninja/2015/09/addendum-letter-from-future.html) post on immutability in pthreads v3:

> In pthreads v3, setting a member of a `Threaded` object (*A*) to another `Threaded` object (*B*) makes the reference that *A* holds to *B* immutable.

Immutability is a performance optimization.

Obviously most use cases for arrays involve mutating the array, which `Threaded` objects are now not always able to support.

*In this particular case, none of the members of the `Threaded` array are `Threaded`.*

pthreads v3 (PHP7) introduces the concept of `Volatile` objects.

> **Volatile**, *Adjective*: Liable to change rapidly and unpredictably, especially for the worse.

`Volatile` objects are slower than `Threaded` objects because they cannot benefit from the performance optimizations that immutability allow us to make.

`Volatile` objects do serve as good alternative to arrays in pthreads v3. pthreads will coerce arrays to `Volatile` objects when they are set as members of `Threaded` objects:

```
<?php
class Test extends Thread {
    public function run(){
        $array = [
            "Hello",
            "World"
        ];

        var_dump($array);

        $this->array = $array;

        var_dump($this->array);
    } 
}

$test = new Test();
$test->start() && $test->join();
?>
```

Will yield:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "World"
}
object(Volatile)#2 (2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "World"
}
```

This causes `$this->array` to behave as expected during the runtime of the `Thread`.

There is a side effect, illustrated by the output of the following code:

```
<?php
class Test extends Thread {
    public function __construct(array $array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function run(){
        var_dump($this->array);
    } 
}

$array = [
    "Hello",
    "World"
];
$test = new Test($array);
$test->start() && $test->join();
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Will yield:

```
object(Volatile)#2 (2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "World"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "World"
}
```

Notice that the `Volatile` object in the `Thread` is disconnected from the `array` that was supplied to it's constructor, so that the main context is still manipulating an `array`.

Automatic coercion serves to reduce the wtfs-per-minute rate when a `Thread` manipulates an array that was passed in from another source.

It's always better to be explicit; Not relying on coercion is the best option.

If you already know that some dependencies will be arrays, then deal with that before setting them as members, avoiding coercion entirely.

It is possible to avoid automatic coercion to `Volatile` by using an explicit cast:

```
<?php
class Test extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        $this->result = (array) [
            "Hello" => "World"
        ];
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->start() && $test->join();
var_dump($test->result);
?>
```

Will yield

```
array(1) {
  ["Hello"]=>
  string(5) "World"
}
```

As the example code shows, this is useful for when you really do want to use an array to store a result. As with PHP5, the array will be serialized for storage.

Comment: How to use arrays function (for example:arrap_pop) for  $this->storage

Comment: You can manipulate it _like_ an array, but its not _an_ array. If you need the object to have functionality then you need to program it differently, rather than [] you might have a push(), allowing you to store indexes and program a pop()

Comment: Since I wrote that last comment, I added merge/shift/chunk/pop to the API, so they are built-in now ...

Comment: "An array is not a thread safe object, simple as that.". I don't get the limitation that makes me not be able to have a *private* array inside a Threaded object (granted I'm vague on the internals of PHP). In C/Java/C++ I can have arrays and whatever objects I want privately (or not privately if I really want). There not "thread safe", but they are *private* (Well they are thread safe if they are private). Even if they are not private I can be stupid and share them among threads with the consequences. I can't even do that in PHP.

Comment: So, asks the lazy programmer, does anybody have a nifty bit of code for pushing and popping and shifting array-as-Volatile objects, that looks pretty and is efficient as well?