# MySQLi wont establish connection within a pthreads worker

Tags: php, mysqli, pthreads

Why cannot a [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) connection be created when using a [pthread](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) [worker](http://php.net/manual/en/class.worker.php) in PHP? When establishing a mysqli and attempting to execute a query, will generatate an error

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   W:\workspace\Sandbox\application.php on line 47

This is my [script](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WEEM8E1N)

```
<?php
    // Application

    // Exceptions
    class MySQLWorkerException extends Exception {}
    class MySQLConnectionException extends Exception {}
    class MySQLQueryException extends Exception {}

    // Worker
    class SQLWorker extends Worker {
        // Class Fields
        protected   $ready;
        protected   $name;

        // MySQLi Object
        protected   $link;

        // MySQL Credentials
        private
                    $host,
                    $username,
                    $password,
                    $database,
                    $port;

        // Constructor
        function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database, $port = 3306) {
            // Set Credentials
            $this->host     = $host;
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->database = $database;
            $this->port     = $port;
        }

        // Methods
        public function run() {
            // Create MySQL link
            $this->link = new mysqli(
                $this->host,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                $this->database,
                $this->port
            );

            $this->link->query("SELECT 1");
            //var_dump($this->link);
            exit;

            // Check for connection error
            if($this->link->connect_errno) {
                throw new MySQLConnectionException('(' . $this->link->connect_errno . '): ' . $this->link->connect_error, E_WARNING);
            }

            //$this->name = sprintf("%s (%lu)", __CLASS__, $this->getThreadId());
            $this->isReady(true);
        }

        public function getConnection() {
            return $this->link;
        }

        protected function isReady($flag = null) { 
            if(is_null($flag)) {
                return ($this->ready);
            } else {
                $this->ready = $flag;
            }
        }
    }

    // MySQL Method Classes
    // STUB: class SQLQuery extends Stackable {}
    // STUB: class SQLResult extends Stackable {}
    // STUB: class SQLPrepare extends Stackable {}

    class SQLQuery extends Stackable {
        // Class Fields
        protected $complete = false;

        // SQL Query
        private $query;
        private $resultmode;

        // SQL Result
        private $result;

        // Constructor
        function __construct($query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
            $this->query = $query;
            $this->resultmode = $resultmode;
        }

        // Methods
        public function run() {
            if($this->worker->isReady()) {
                if(!$this->result = mysqli_query($this->worker->link, $this->query, $this->resultmode)) {
                    throw new MySQLQueryException('(' . $this->worker->link->errno . '): ' . $this->worker->link->error, E_WARNING);
                }
            } else {
                throw new MySQLWorkerException('Worker is not ready', E_ERROR);
            }

            $this->complete = true;
            $this->notify();
        }

        public function isComplete() {
            return ($this->complete);
        }

        public function GetResults() {
            return $this->result;
        }

        public function ReadResults() {
            $response = null;
            while($row = $this->result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $response[] = $row;
            }

            if($translateRows) {
                if(count($response) == 1) {
                    $response = end($response);

                    if(count($response) == 1) {
                        $response = end($response);
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->result->close();
            return $response;
        }
    }


    // Program
    $config = [
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'database'  => 'testdatabase',
        'port'      => 3306
    ];

    // MySQL Worker
    $worker = new SQLWorker($config['host'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database'], $config['port']);
    $worker->start();

    // Create Query
    $query = new SQLQuery("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1");

    // Give the query to the worker
    // $worker->stack($query);

    /* In reality we would have done a lot of shit here while the query executes. */

    // If the query isnt complete, wait up.
    $query->wait();

    // Holy shit, lets var_dump this bad boy
    // var_dump($query);

    // Shutdown the Worker Thread. We don't want any memleaks!
    $worker->shutdown();
```

Comment: What's line 81? It's a blank line in my editor.

Comment: @Fred-ii- See line 47. I did some changes to the script in the topic. Removed unnecessary comments etc.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Apr 30 2014 11:20:55)

Comment: What I find strange is that you have two `run()` functions. One for `$this->link = new mysqli` and one for `if($this->worker->isReady())` wouldn't that be a conflict of sorts?

Comment: @Fred-ii- First `run()` is to start the Thread (worker) and second to complete a task inside that Thread (see line #150). Infact the second `run()` is never called, see line #156; The task is never assigned to the thread, because its commented out. I need a working worker before i can assign tasks to the thread, that's the reason for this question! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59731/discussion-between-ole-kristian-aanensen-and-fred-ii).

Comment: Sorry, I can't chat, I've got to leave. I'll +1 to see if anyone can pick up on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some working code ...

```
<?php

class SQLWorker extends Worker {

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port = 3306) {
        $this->hostname = $hostname;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function run() {
        /* the static class scope acts as a kind of thread local storage for this class */
        self::$connection = new MySQLi
            ($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->port);
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return self::$connection;
    }

    protected $hostname;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $database;
    protected $port;

    protected static $connection;
}

class SQLTask extends Threaded {
    public function __construct($sql) {
        $this->sql = $sql;
    }

    public function run() {
        /* fetch static (thread local) connection */
        $link = $this->worker->getConnection();

        if ($link) {
            /* execute query, keep result in local scope */
            $result = $link->query($this->sql);

            /* build up results as normal array */
            while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        }

        /* store results in a fetchable form */
        $this->rows = $rows;
    }

    public function getResults() {
        return $this->rows;
    }
}

$pool = new Pool(4, 
    SQLWorker::class, 
    ["localhost", "username", "password", "database"]);

$pool->submit(
    $task = new SQLTask("SELECT 1"));

$pool->shutdown();

/* you have your normal array of data here */
var_dump($task->getResults());
```

The basic problem is that complex objects like mysqli objects will not play nice with safety implemented on pthreads objects, therefore do not write such objects to the object scope, keep them in static (thread local), method, or global scope (globals are horrible).

In addition to this, your use of synchronization is not sane. You should only ever wait *for* something, as explained: https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782

Comment: Joe, thanks for this. Is this threaded object behaviour responsible for [the apparent immutability](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26150578/472495) of instance-level objects? (See the example in the question from another contributer, and one from me in my answer).

Comment: Aha, you've [explained it here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14800297/472495). It seems there are two solutions to this - the one here is to make an array/object `static` inside the `Worker`, and the other one is to use an object that extends `Stackable`. Is the purpose of the latter just to prevent concurrent threads from modifying a shared resource simultaneously?