# Why do some threaded array operations in PHP appear not to work?

Tags: php, pthreads

I have this thread class that utilises the `pthread` PHP extension:

```
class Task extends Thread
{
    protected $arr = array();

    public function run()
    {
        $this->arr[] = 1;
        $this->arr[] = 2;
        $this->arr[] = 3;
        var_dump($this->arr);
    }
}
$thread = new Task();
$thread->start();
$thread->join();
```

The output inexplicably shows an empty array. Could anybody briefly explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution but not a solid explanation, so more answers would be very welcome.

Here is my `Threaded` child (trimmed for the sake of brevity):

```
class ObjectConstructorThreaded extends Threaded
{
    protected $worker;
    protected $className;
    protected $parameters;
    protected $objectKey;

    public function __construct($className, $parameters)
    {
        $this->className = $className;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    public function setWorker(\Worker $worker)
    {
        $this->worker = $worker;
    }

    protected function getWorker()
    {
        return $this->worker;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($this->className);
        $instance = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($this->parameters);
        $this->objectKey = $this->getWorker()->notifyObject($instance);
    }

    public function getObjectKey()
    {
        return $this->objectKey;
    }
}
```

And the `Worker` (again trimmed):

```
class ObjectServer extends Worker
{
    protected $count = 0;
    protected $objects = array();

    public function notifyObject($object)
    {
        $key = $this->generateHandle();

        /*
        // Weird, this does not add anything to the stack
        $this->objects[$key] = $object;

        // Try pushing - fail!
        $this->objects[] = $object;

        // This works fine? (but not very useful)
        $this->objects = array($key => $object);
        */

        // Try adding - also fine!
        $this->objects = $this->objects + array($key => $object);

        return $key;
    }
}
```

Finally, to kick off the thread:

```
$thread = new ObjectServer();
$thread->start();
$threaded = new ObjectConstructorThreaded($className, $parameters);
$threaded->setWorker($this->worker);
$thread->stack($threaded);
```

As you can see from the unadulterated comments I wrote at the time, attempts to insert or push to the array failed, but rewriting it (by setting it to a fixed value or a merge of the old value and the new entry) seems to work.

I'm therefore regarding threading as making non-trivial types (arrays and objects) effectively immutable, and that they can only be reset and not modified. I've had the same experience with serialisable classes too.

As to *why* this is the case, or if there is a better approach, I will update this answer if I find out!

Comment: I suspect [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25446901/472495) is one explanation - change the instance-level array to a static, and it seems to work fine. Also, arrays can be modelled [using a Stackable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14800297/472495).