# Impossible to assign simple Array on Stackable

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, pthreads

I am trying to create a library for codeigniter that uses pthread, everything works fine but when i want to assign a value to an array this don't work with traditional $a['key'] = 'val';

Small Test Exemple : **( updated )**

```
class Test {
    protected $core;
    protected $stack;

    public function init(){
        $this->stack = new Test_Stack();
        $this->core = new Test_Core($this->stack);
    }

    public function do_test(){
        return $this->core->assign();
    }
}


class Test_Stack extends Stackable {
    protected $a;

    function __construct(){
        $this->a = array();
    }

    protected function test(){ // Call from other class extends Threads
        $this->a['key1'] = 'NOWORK';
        print_r($this->a); // THIS RETURN NOTHING   

        $this->a = array_merge($this->a, array('key1' => 'WORK'));
        print_r($this->a); // NOW THIS GOOD RETURN Key1..
    }

    public function run(){}
}

class Test_Core {
    protected $thread;
    protected $stack;

    function __construct($s){
       $this->stack = $s;
    }

    public function assign(){
        $this->thread = new Test_Thread($this->stack);
        $this->thread->start();

        $this->thread->join();
    }
}

class Test_Thread extends Thread{
    protected $stack;

    function __construct($s){
       $this->stack = $s;
    }

    public function run(){
        $this->stack->test();
    }
}
```

I write this basic code without testing but it's the same structure of my lib and need this to extends test_stack and add or change test function for exemple.

Even if works now, I would understand why I can't assign my array normally ?
Or rather, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me! Output which i get: `Array ( [key1] => NOWORK ) Array ( [key1] => WORK )`

Comment: oK it's very strange, i will post new code that is more like mine implementation. Thx Rizier123

Comment: Do you have notices enabled?

Comment: possible explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796674/a-php-pthreads-thread-class-cant-use-array

Comment: Yes Marek, error_reporting = E_ALL, display_error On and nothing appears

Comment: I think the solution is through Thx LuckyBurger I'll try to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK array isn't thread safe, should be used stackable, this do the trick :

Libraries/Test.php :

```
class Test {
    protected $core;
    protected $stack;

    public function init(){
        $this->stack = new Test_Stack();
        $this->core = new Test_Core($this->stack);
    }

    public function do_test(){
        $this->core->assign();
        $this->core->assign();
        $this->core->assign();
    }

    public function get_a(){
        return $this->core->get_a();
    }
}

class Test_Array_Stack extends Stackable {
    public function run(){}
}

class Test_Stack extends Stackable {
    protected function test($a){
        $a[] = 'WORK';
    }
    public function run(){}
}

class Test_Core {
    protected $thread;
    protected $stack;
    protected $a;

    function __construct($s){
       $this->stack = $s;

       $this->a = new Test_Array_Stack();
    }

    public function assign(){
        $this->thread = new Test_Thread($this->stack, $this->a);
        $this->thread->start();

        $this->thread->synchronized(function($thread){
            $thread->wait();
        }, $this->thread);

        return $this->a;
    }

    public function get_a(){
        return $this->a;
    }
}

class Test_Thread extends Thread{
    protected $stack;
    protected $a;

    function __construct($s, $a){
       $this->stack = $s;
       $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function run(){
        $this->stack->test($this->a);

        $this->synchronized(function($thread){
            $thread->notify();
        }, $this);
    }
}
```

You can extends Test_Stack to create lib extension more useful for my project, like this on other file Test_Info.php :

```
require_once APPPATH.'libraries/Test.php';

class Test_Info extends Test {

    function init(){
        $this->stack = new Test_Info_Stack();
        $this->core = new Test_Core($this->stack);
    }
}

class Test_Info_Stack extends Test_Stack {
    protected function test($a){
        parent::test($a);
        $a[] = 'INFO';
    }
}
```

And usage on controller:

```
function index(){
    //without extension
    $this->load->library('Test');
    $this->test->init();
    $this->test->do_test();
    print_r($this->test->get_a());

    //with extension
    $this->load->library('Test_Info');
    $this->test_info->init();
    $this->test_info->do_test();
    print_r($this->test_info->get_a());
}
```

It took me some time, i hope it will help someone and LuckyBurger thank you for the explanation link.

Answer (score 0):

Working in Mine :

```
class Stack  {
    protected $a;

    function __construct(){
        $this->a = array();
    }

    function test(){ 
         $this->a['key1'] = 'NOWORK';
         print_r($this->a); // THIS RETURN NOTHING


         $this->a = array_merge($this->a, array('key1' => 'WORK'));
         print_r($this->a); // NOW THIS GOOD RETURN Key1..
    }
}


$obj = new Stack();
$obj->test();
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [key1] => NOWORK
)
Array
(
    [key1] => WORK
)
```

Comment: Yes Tiger thx but you don't use Pthread and Stackable class :(