# PHP pthreads : impossible to create object correctly in constructor

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I am new to threads in PHP and I have a problem with classes extending Thread.
I need to store an object given in the constructor parameters into a SplObjectStorage but I am unable to do it.
The SplObjectStorage object remains empty even after attaching an object.

When I remove the "extends Thread", it works correctly but I need to use threads.

Here is an example :

```
<?php

class MyClass extends Thread
{
    protected $variable;
    public function __constructor($object)
    {
        $this->variable = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->variable->attach($object);

        $storage = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $storage->attach($object);

        var_dump($this->variable); // shows empty SplObjectStorage
        var_dump($storage); // shows SplObjectStorage with $object inside it
        var_dump($object); // shows the object
    }
    public function run() {}
}
```

Have you got an idea ?
I want $this->variable to be like $storage after the attachment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The author of PHP pthreads has already [answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14800297/2032498) a couple of times on Stack Overflow.

Objects not extending [`Threaded`](http://php.net/Threaded) aren't considered thread-safe and are therefore serialized/copied by pthreads.

You can make "thread-safe" classes from normal classes at runtime with [`Threaded::extend()`](http://php.net/threaded.extend). But be very careful. The underlying implementation might not be thread-safe. ([`SplObjectStorage`](http://php.net/SplObjectStorage) fails here, by the way.)

I'm afraid you have to create/use `SplObjectStorage` thread-locally.

```
protected static $variable; // will be NULL in thread's context
```

---

*OK, I must correct myself here a bit. I'm still in the process of learning pthreads myself.*

Actually, you can use normal objects as class properties. But you have to access them somewhat unconventionally (and it's not very fast):

```
$storage = new \SplObjectStorage;
$storage->attach($object);
$this->variable = $storage; // object gets serialized

$storage = $this->variable // object gets unserialized

// work with $storage normally...

// ...and write it back:
$this->variable = $storage
```

Also note that you're working on **copies** when using the technique above. Other threads won't see changes until you write the object back. You might want to use [`Threaded::synchronized()`](http://php.net/threaded.synchronized) here.

---

You always have to keep in mind that `objects` and `arrays` will be **serialized** when setting a `Threaded` property and **unserialized** when getting that property.

PS: Working with `strings` as `Threaded` properties is also very slow...