# Cannot assign value to array using PHP pthreads

Tags: php, arrays, class, pthreads

I have the following code where I'm attempting to assign a value to an array in a class that uses php pthreads to no avail - I have looked at solutions that suggest using stacks to no avail either:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    class WorkerThreads extends Thread
        {
            private $fromlist;

            public function __construct()
            {
                    $this->fromlist = array();
            }

            public function run()
            {
                   $this->fromlist=array("hello"=>1,2);
                   $this->fromlist['hi']="!!!";
                   $this->fromlist[] = array("ho", 1);
            }
        }

            $workers = new WorkerThreads();
            $workers->start();
            print_r($workers);
```

I get the following results:

```
WorkerThreads Object
(
    [fromlist] => Array
        (
            [hello] => 1
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

I was expecting to see additional array elements - try as I may I cannot get it to add more elements.

I've checked the syntax and it seems fine - the problem appears to be how to use an array in pthreads - I can't seem to make sense of how to do that.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Or suggest some code for the above so I can get to a working solution?

Comment: Why are you doing `private $fromlist = array();` inside of your `__construct()` method...?

Comment: Typo.. whilst debugging I forgot to remove that... It still does not work - I think arrays may not be serializable in multithreading...

Comment: possible duplicate of [A PHP/pthreads Thread class can't use array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796674/a-php-pthreads-thread-class-cant-use-array)

Comment: Nope - not duplicate of that question Joe as that expects same space arrays - my code does not. I've posted the answer below which does not appear on that q&a.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the $fromlist variable to the run() function solves the problem.