# Php - Pthreads/Speedup and data save

Tags: php, multithreading

I have 2 goals, one is to reduce my script run time from 6 minutes to less than 30 secs.

I was able to reduce my script to 1.2 minutes by using php extension pthreads. I hope that someone can further show me how to optimize my script down below 30 secs. I have only been working with pthreads for 2 days and I am NOT an expert on classes/objects, so I could have made some seriously rookie choices in optimizing with pthreads and classes.

Most important to understand is that LARGE text files are being read in —
there are 169,000 serial numbers in each file and each serial number is on a new line, so file, if opened would look like below:

100 23 56 230 45

345 279 34 56 800

11 23 600 435 67

45 350 567 89 99

89 345 457 88 1  —169,000 of these lines

I append 30 of these files to a string called $lines_ophold and when that is finished I explode $lines_ophold  into an array called $lines_op and perform array_keys(array_flip()) to remove any duplicate serial numbers from $lines_op array. I then store $lines_op array into another array called $linesmaster1, and that array will in the end have an array count of 15 (see for loop variable $t). This whole process has to be done 9 separate times, that is why I have 9 pthread workers.

PLEASE NOTE MY SECOND QUESTION: I can easily get and save the data in my original script from $linesmaster1 array to be used later. BUT I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO GET AND SAVE THE DATA FROM $linesmaster1 (for each of the 9 pthread workers) to be used later in the script within the pthreads version.

Much appreciate any help on optimization below 30 secs and answer of how to get and save data from the $linesmaster1 array in pthreads code.

******************ORIGINAL CODE (NO PTHREADS)***************

```
 for($j=0; $j<9; $j++)

     { 

     for($t=0; $t<15; $t++)

{

$lines_ophold="";

for($x=0; $x<30; $x++)

{   
$lines_ophold .=file_get_contents("/".$j."/test_".$x.".txt")."\r\n";


}

$lines_op=array_keys(array_flip(explode("\r\n",$lines_ophold)));

$linesmaster1[$t]=$lines_op;

unset($lines_op);

} }
```

*****************SPEEDUP CODE WITH PTHREADS*****************

```
global $linesmaster1;

class WorkerThreads extends Thread

{
private $workerId;
public $lines_ophold;
public $data;

public function __construct($id)
{
        $this->workerId = $id;
        $this->data = $id;
}
public function run()
    {

 for($t=0; $t<15; $t++)
   {

$lines_ophold="";

for($x=0; $x<30; $x++)
{   
$lines_ophold .=file_get_contents("/".$this->workerId."/test_".$x.".txt")."\r\n";

}

$lines_op=array_keys(array_flip(explode("\r\n",$lines_ophold)));

$linesmaster1[$t]=$lines_op;

unset($lines_op);

} 
    }
}

// Worker pool
$workers = [];
 // Initialize and start the threads

foreach (range(0, 8) as $i) {

    $workers[$i] = new WorkerThreads($i);

    $workers[$i]->start();
}

// Let the threads come back
foreach (range(0, 8) as $i) {

    $workers[$i]->join();

$workers[$i]->data;

}
```

Comment: You can profile the speed of your code with [xhprof](https://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof).

Comment: You can probably replace all this code with `cat * | sort -nu`

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for your reply! I worked through this but it was much slower than my pthread code posted above because that is 30 large files having to be cat together (and duplicates removed, plus new lines added), over and over and over again on the command line using exec(); I am not sure how much of what I wrote above you read but it does explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to how to access the array data from this post below under the php 7 section:
[A PHP/pthreads Thread class can't use array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796674/a-php-pthreads-thread-class-cant-use-array)

In short, in php 7 arrays have immutability by default so you can either extend volatile or cast the array object to a normal array. I chose to simply cast all array objects. UPDATED CODE is below:

```
class WorkerThreads extends Thread

{
private $workerId;
public $lines_ophold;

public function __construct($id)
{
        $this->workerId = $id;

}
public function run()
    {

 for($t=0; $t<15; $t++)
   {

$lines_ophold="";

for($x=0; $x<30; $x++)
{   
$lines_ophold .=file_get_contents("/folder/".$this->workerId."/pos3.txt")."\r\n";

}

$lines_op=array_keys(array_flip(explode("\r\n",$lines_ophold)));
$this->result=(array) $lines_op; //CAST THE ARRAY object

$linesmaster1[$t]=$this->result;

unset($lines_op);

} 

print_r($linesmaster1);
    }
}

// Worker pool
$workers = [];
 // Initialize and start the threads

foreach (range(0, 8) as $i) {

    $workers[$i] = new WorkerThreads($i);

    $workers[$i]->start();
}

// Let the threads come back
foreach (range(0, 8) as $i) {

    $workers[$i]->join();

}
```